# ASP.NET MVC Custom Type List in Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a view that takes a PaginatedList (like in Nerd Dinner sample). The page works as intended. Now I have added a partial view that takes the same PaginatedList and I call RnederPartial inside the first view. ASP.NET throws a exception that I can't seem to resolve.

PaginatedList Code:

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        TotalCount = source.Count();
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);
        this.AddRange(source.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 0);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex + 1 < TotalPages);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    const int pageSize = 10;

    var workstations = itilRepository.FindAllWorkstations();

    var paginatedWorkstations = new PaginatedList<Workstation>(workstations, page ?? 0, pageSize);

    return View("Index", paginatedWorkstations);
}
```

Top of Index View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ITILDatabase.Helpers.PaginatedList<ITILDatabase.Models.Workstation>>" %>
```

I call the partial view in the Index view as follows:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Workstations", Model); %>
```

Top of Workstations Partial View:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ITILDatabase.Helpers.PaginatedList<ITILDatabase.Models.Workstation>>" %>
```

The error I receive is:

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\d2889d23\c6192b3e\App_Web_workstations.ascx.a8d08dba.tgrd74s0.0.cs(156): error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ASP.views_home_workstations_ascx' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl'

If anyone knows why I am getting this error I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank You!

Comment: Just wanted to tell that's not a good idea to steal this PaginatedList code 1:1. It demands all items to be fetched from database.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your Workstations Partial View's top should look like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ITILDatabase.Helpers.PaginatedList<ITILDatabase.Models.Workstation>>" %>
```

Change ViewPage to ViewUserControl

Comment: I noticed this, but could not remember what it should be like. ^^

Comment: Thank You, I can't believe I didn't see that!

Comment: Thx, same problem for me, was VS created the control as System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage not ViewUserControl.